# draw live chart using ble device data, but occurring time delay

Tags: flutter, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

Bluetooth communication is in progress with the EMG measurement ble device, but while receiving data by activating notify, the data is not immediately received when the device is attached to the body and moving, resulting in a time delay.

Does anyone know about this problem?

this code is after connecting,
notify property activate, parsing data, sink add data
use parsing func, return number type int

```
 for (BluetoothService service in bleServices) {
      for (BluetoothCharacteristic c in service.characteristics) {
        if (c.properties.notify && c.descriptors.isNotEmpty) {
          if (!c.isNotifying) {
            try {
              await c.setNotifyValue(true);
              notifyDatas[c.uuid.toString()] = 0;

              c.lastValueStream.listen((value) async {
                print('data ====> $value');
                setState(() {
                  int streamData = processNotifyData(value);
                  print('data after parsing ====> $streamData');
                  notifyDatas[c.uuid.toString()] = streamData;
                  if(streamData != 0){
                    dataStreamController.sink.add(streamData);
                  }
                });
              });
            } catch (e) {
              // debugPrint('error ${c.uuid} $e');
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
```

this code is char.dart
char's x is DateTime, y is receive data

```
 void initState() {
  super.initState();
   widget.dataStreamController.stream.listen((data) {
    debugPrint("subscription data ====> $data");
    if(data != 0){
      setState(() {
        dataPoints.add(DataPoint(DateTime.now(), data));
        if(dataPoints.length > maxDataPoints){
          dataPoints.removeAt(0);
        }
      });
    }
  });
```

}

using background, but data serialization problem occurred.
using streamController and sink.add() but, delayed between data send & receive and visualization on chart.